# Delete Facebook App with Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a Facebook authentication system using the Graph Api v2.8.
The website that makes the request requires the user's email.

Problem: the app is added on the user's Facebook regardless he unchecks or not the email permission option.

Is there any way of preventing the app being added on the user's facebook when he refuses to share his email?
If not, how can I remove the app from the user's facebook?

Thks in advance.

Comment: Hope you are aware that lots of user might not even have an email address on file with Facebook ... (for example if they signed up using only their mobile.)

Comment: Well noted. Thks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution that solved the problem, by removing the app from the user's Facebook:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email');
$userNode = $response->getGraphUser();

if (!isset($userNode['email']) || (isset($userNode['email']) && !$userNode['email'])) {
    $fb->delete($userNode['id'] . '/permissions');
}
```

The line:
`$fb->delete($userNode['id'] . '/permissions');`
deletes the user app.